# Smooth transition with filter Mapbox (setPaintProperty)

Tags: javascript, expression, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to understand how the filters (expressions) in the setPaintProperty, setLayoutProperty and even setFilter methods work, as I'm noticing some peculiar behavior with transitions.

It seems that transitions are not applied when a filter is used in these methods. Here's an example (https://codepen.io/cladjidane/pen/MWzLPeE), showing that only saintPaintProperty without a filter applies a smooth transition. But as soon as you add a filter, it doesn't work anymore.

```
map.setPaintProperty("state-fills", "fill-opacity", 0); // Smooth transition
// ...
map.setPaintProperty("state-fills", "fill-opacity", ["case", ["==", ["get", "STATE_NAME"],  "Florida"], 1, 0]); // No smooth transition
```

I did read somewhere that "it's technically impossible", but I'd like to know more about it and possibly an alternative way of handling the appearance/disappearance of layers with a soft effect (if possible, a high-performance one).

Comment: Did you try this with set feature state?

Comment: @Malcolm I thought about it, but I don't know why I dropped the idea, but I'll be interested if you have an example ^^ Otherwise I've managed with a barbarian technique, but it's dirty. 
`this._map.setPaintProperty(layer.id, 'fill-opacity-transition', {duration: 0, delay: 0});`
`this._map.setPaintProperty(layer.id, 'fill-opacity', 0);`
`setTimeout(function(){
  map.setPaintProperty(layer.id, 'fill-opacity-transition', {duration: 300, delay: 0});
  map.setPaintProperty(layer.id, 'fill-opacity', 1);
}, 300)`